# Can I recover e-mail account settings from SeaMonkey?

Tags: email, data-recovery, email-client, pop3, seamonkey

One of my e-mail accounts is POP3 only. This means that having it set up on multiple computers might get confusing. So I deleted it from SeaMonkey on my desktop (Windows Vista) before creating it in Thunderbird on my laptop (Ubuntu 13.10).

However, I can’t create it in Thunderbird. I must have some of the details wrong. I’m pretty confident I’ve got the password right, so something else must be wrong. The e-mail data from SeaMonkey still exists*, however, that seems to contain only the actual e-mails. As far as I can tell, the login data has disappeared. Would it exist anywhere in recoverable format? (I guess the name of the actual mailserver can be inferred from the name of the folder.)

* I backed up the folder `SeaMonkey/Profiles/vh64vf7c.default/Mail/mail.iolfree.ie` before I deleted the account; in fact that was unnecessary, as it’s still there even after deletion.

Comment: Unless you deleted the profile data for SeaMonkey it still exists on your desktop.

Comment: Yes, I said that. The folder containing the e-mail data still exists. How do I get the actual account settings out of that? I assume they're in there somewhere.

Comment: You didn't **mention** the login details did not exist.  You are basically out of luck the data file that contained it no longer exists.

Answer (score 0):

SeaMonkey stores the email account settings along with the password in a SQLite database called signons.sqlite, which resides in your SeaMonkey profile directory. With [this trick](http://www.windowspassword.org/retrieve-saved-password-from-firefox-thunderbird-seamonkey-and-flock/) you can extract the passwords from the signons.sqlite file:

1. Start the Firefox Password Recovery program. Click on the "Recover
   From File" button.
2. From the pop up window, specify your SeaMonkey profile directory.
3. Click OK. It will reveal your email account passwords saved in your
   SeaMonkey profile.

I hope this helps!

Comment: Could you possibly summarize the steps from that link here? External sources tend to change or disappear, making answers here invalid.